# Unable to start PHP Server in linux command line

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, php

I tried

```
php -s localhost:4444 WebContent/
```

But my ubuntu terminal gives

Usage: php [options] [-f]  [--] [args...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switch is a capital S and you will need php 5.4 or above.

```
php -S localhost:4444 WebContent/
```

Comment: Thank You.. It saved my day.. Now i can monitor errors in php code in the terminal itself instead in eclipse..

Comment: My ubuntu has just ph v 5.3 That is my problem.. Now All clear..